# Fortran: Set operations

Tags: search, set, fortran

**Fortran:** There are two large arrays of integers, the goal is to find out if they have any number in common or not, **how?**
You may consider that both are in the same size (case 1) or in different sizes (case 2). It is possible also that they have many common numbers repeated, so this should be handled to avoid unnecessary search or operators.
The simplest way is to do Brute-Force search which is not appropriate. We are thinking about `SET` operations similar to **Python** as the following:

```
a = set([integers])
b = set([integers])
incommon = len(a.intersection(b)) > 0    #True if so, otherwise False
```

So for example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [0,6,7,8,9]
sa = set(a)
sb = set(b)
incommon = len(sa.intersection(sb)) > 0
>>> incommon: False
b = [0,6,7,8,1]
incommon = len(sa.intersection(sb)) > 0
>>> incommon: True
```

**How to implement this in Fortran?** note that arrays are of large size (>10000) and the operation would repeat for million times!

**Updates:**
[regarding the comment for the question] We absolutely have tried many ways that we knew. As mentioned BFS method, for example. It works but is not efficient for two reasons: 1) the nature of the method which requires large iterations, 2) the code we could implement. The accepted answer (by yamajun) was very informative to us much more than the question itself. How easy implementation of Quick-Sort, Shrink and Isin all are very nicely thought and elegantly implemented. Our appreciation goes for such prompt and perfect solution.

Comment: +1 @steabert - That's obvious from the question that the OP (has) have tired some ways. It is an interesting question to me.

Comment: @steabert Absolutely we have had some trials. We are not new in Fortran at all. You might be smarter than us but we are trying our best.

Comment: I think the best way is to implement the set class in more or less the same way as it is done in python. I believe the python implementation uses a hash map, and that the number of operations scales for `sa = set(a)` as `O(len(a))`, for `sb = set(b)` as `O(len(b))`, and for `sa.intersection(sb)` as `O(len(sb))`. That is, overall, the scaling is linear to the length of the longer one of the original list. If you sort the original lists, the sorting cost will scale more than linear. You can compare the performance of the set method and the list-sorting (or numpy-array-sorting) method in python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe this will work.

**added from here**

The main idea is using intrinsic function ANY().

1. ANY(x(:) == y) returns .true. if a scalar value y exists in an array x. When y is also an array ANY(x == y) returns x(1)==y(1) & x(2)==y(2) &..., so we have to use do loop for each element of y.

Now we try to delete duplicate numbers in the arrays.

1. First we sort the arrays. Quick-sort can be written concisely in a Haskell-like manner. 
   (Reference : Arjen Markus, ACM Fortran Forum 27 (2008) 2-5.)
   But because recursion consumes stacks, Shell-sort might be a better choice, which does not require extra memories. It is often stated in textbooks that Shell-sort works in O(N^3/2~5/4), but it works much faster using special gap functions.[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_sort)
2. Next we delete duplicate numbers by comparing successive elements using the idea of zip pairs. [x(2)/=x(1), ..., x(n)/=x(n-1)] We need to add extra one element to match array size. The intrinsic function PACK() is used as a Filter.

**to here**

```
  program SetAny
    implicit none
    integer, allocatable :: ia(:), ib(:)
! fortran2008
!    allocate(ia, source = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5])
!    allocate(ib, source = [0,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9])
    allocate(ia(size([1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5])))
    allocate(ib(size([0,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9])))
    ia = [1,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5,2,3,4,5]
    ib = [0,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9,6,7,8,9]

    print *, isin( shrnk( ia ), shrnk( ib ) )
    stop
contains
  logical pure function isin(ia, ib)
    integer, intent(in) :: ia(:), ib(:)
    integer :: i
    isin = .true.
    do i = 1, size(ib)
      if ( any(ia == ib(i)) ) return 
    end do
    isin = .false.
    return
  end function isin

  pure function shrnk(ia) result(res)
    integer, intent(in) :: ia(:)
    integer, allocatable :: res(:) ! f2003
    integer :: iwk(size(ia))
    iwk = qsort(ia)
    res = pack(iwk, [.true., iwk(2:) /= iwk(1:)]) ! f2003
    return
  end function shrnk

  pure recursive function qsort(ia) result(res)
    integer, intent(in) :: ia(:)
    integer :: res(size(ia))
    if (size(ia) .lt. 2) then 
     res = ia
    else
     res = [ qsort( pack(ia(2:), ia(2:) < ia(1)) ), ia(1), qsort( pack(ia(2:), ia(2:) >= ia(1)) ) ]
    end if
    return
  end function qsort

end program SetAny
```

**Shell sort**

```
  pure function ssort(ix) ! Shell Sort
    integer, intent(in) :: ix(:)  
    integer, allocatable :: ssort(:)
    integer :: i, j, k, kmax, igap, itmp
    ssort = ix
    kmax = 0
    do  ! Tokuda's gap sequence ; h_k=Ceiling( (9(9/4)^k-4)/5 ), h_k < 4N/9 ; O(N)~NlogN 
      if ( ceiling( (9.0 * (9.0 / 4.0)**(kmax + 1) - 4.0) / 5.0 ) > size(ix) * 4.0 / 9.0 ) exit
      kmax = kmax + 1
    end do

    do k = kmax, 0, -1
      igap = ceiling( (9.0 * (9.0 / 4.0)**k - 4.0) / 5.0 )
      do i = igap, size(ix)
        do j = i - igap, 1, -igap
          if ( ssort(j) <= ssort(j + igap) ) exit
            itmp           = ssort(j)
            ssort(j)       = ssort(j + igap)
            ssort(j + igap) = itmp
          end do
        end do
      end do
    return
  end function ssort
```

Comment: +1 I tested your code ([Code-Block Fortran](http://www.codeblocks.org), [GFortran](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortran)) and it works perfectly!

Comment: +2 Thanks a lot for the sample code. It works very well. Now we can develop it for our problem, hopefully.

Comment: I don't think responding to a how-to-implement-this question with a code dump is a good answer.  Would have been better to explain why you use qsort and how it works.

Comment: I added some explanation. I was in a hurry so I couldn't check my program much nor write explanation. I also added shell-sort routine which can avoid stack-overflow!

Comment: qsort( pack(ia(2:), ia(2:) < ia(1))
                           |    |
When I changed < to .lt. (because of HTML syntax I couldn't use < or > ), It seems I changed ia(1) to ia(2) by mistake.